# I get an error after adding Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite to my Xamarin.iOS project

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to use Entityframework core and sqlite in my project but I keep getting this error message "the type dbconnection is defined in an assembly that is not referenced".

What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Well, a first guess would be to add System.Data to your project, you know, like the error message says?

Comment: DbConnection is in System.Data.Common which is not a .NET standard library.

Comment: The error says otherwise, it's telling you to add `System.Data`

Comment: Why is there no System.Data in netstandard 2.0 https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/30